# Can we delete a node in Context Object of step function? using SFN input/output processing?

Tags: aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

For instance if a state produces following output

```
{
  "Name":"Sup",
  "ID":"sjkjsk",
  "Resources":[1,2,3,4]
}
```

I want the output to not include `"Resources"`, like below

```
{
  "Name":"Sup",
  "ID":"sjkjsk"
}
```

How can I achieve this step function input/output processing?